# Making music on a Mac

Tags: music, ios

I am making an iOS game and I wanted to make hawaiian music for the game. What would be a good solution for a Mac? I don't want to use GarageBand.

**Edit**

I need the song to have a ukulele sound like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nqj_mtdpV-o)

Comment: What do you know about music writing? How do you plan to create this music: drum machine, synth, writing a score etc... What you have in mind so far will determine which tools to look for.

Comment: … duplicate of [Music composing software](http://superuser.com/questions/426848/music-composing-software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal and every day used favourite application for recording, editing and converting sounds:

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

> Audacity is a free, easy-to-use and multilingual audio editor and recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating systems. You can use Audacity to:

**Features resume:**

- Record live audio.
- Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
- Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
- Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
- Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
- And more! See the [complete list of features](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features).

As a personal note: *I use this for my radio station and it has never let me down.*

---

**EDITED**

On the comment is mentioned that you need to write down the notes, an easy-to-use application that I've "played around" in the past is [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/):

> MuseScore is a free cross-platform WYSIWYG music notation program that offers a cost-effective alternative to commercial programs such as Sibelius, Finale and Capella.
>   You can print beautifully engraved sheet music or save it as PDF or MIDI file.

Comment: Thanks for thre comment. I already have audacity. I need to write out the notes not take premade clips and put them together.

Comment: I'm not much of a musician at that level, per say, but I've used MuseScore in the past just for fun, but the end result was quite good. Combined with Audacity, a world of solutions presents it self :)

Comment: I'm looking for an application that will have the tools to let me write something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nqj_mtdpV-o

Comment: You can perform that with any of the suggested applications, but like any other, it requires knowledge and hard work! The music example that you've provided has someone singing, instruments and a smooth combination of both, just like any other music!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want musical notation software. Try [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/), it should be what you're looking for.  From its web site:

> MuseScore is a free cross-platform WYSIWYG music notation program that offers a cost-effective alternative to commercial programs such as Sibelius, Finale and Capella.
>   You can print beautifully engraved sheet music or save it as PDF or MIDI file.
>
> Some highlights:
>
> - WYSIWYG, notes are entered on a "virtual note sheet"
> - Unlimited number of staves
> - Up to four voices per staff
> - Easy and fast note entry with your keyboard, mouse, or MIDI keyboard
> - Integrated sequencer and FluidSynth software synthesizer
> - Import and export of MusicXML and Standard MIDI Files
> - Available for Windows, Mac and Linux
> - Translated in 48 languages
> - GNU GPL licensed

[image: screenshot of MuseScore]

You might also want to play with [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/):

> LMMS is a free cross-platform alternative to commercial programs like FL Studio®, which allow you to produce music with your computer. This includes the creation of melodies and beats, the synthesis and mixing of sounds, and arranging of samples. You can have fun with your MIDI-keyboard and much more; all in a user-friendly and modern interface.
>
> Features:
>
> - Song-Editor for composing songs
> - A Beat+Bassline-Editor for creating beats and basslines
> - An easy-to-use Piano-Roll for editing patterns and melodies
> - An FX mixer with 64 FX channels and arbitrary number of effects allow unlimited mixing possibilities
> - Many powerful instrument and effect-plugins out of the box
> - Full user-defined track-based automation and computer-controlled automation sources
> - Compatible with many standards such as SoundFont2, VST(i), LADSPA, GUS Patches, and MIDI
> - Import of MIDI and FLP (Fruityloops® Project) files

[image: Screenshot of LMMS]

Comment: I'm looking for an application that will have the tools to let me write something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nqj_mtdpV-o

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do almost everything you need to do if you have Logic Pro... and in case you are looking for ambient sounds like Telefon Tel Aviv, you can always go for Ableton Live..but Logic has a huge collection of sounds that many commercial producers use in the industry

Comment: I'm looking for an application that will have the tools to let me write something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nqj_mtdpV-o

Comment: i would suggest that you can go for Logic Pro without any hesitation